# Ubuntu software centre does not open after installing iTunes

Tags: software-center

After installing itunes via Playonlinux, the Ubuntu Software Centre refuses to open. I did get an error message that iTunes was not properly installed and should be reinstalled. But I cannot open the Software Centre to uninstall iTunes. My laptop is also now much slower.

How do I fix it?

Comment: The Software Center will not be able to help you install or uninstall Itunes.  Open a terminal window (ctrl+alt+t) and enter the commands `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get -f install` - please paste any error outputs from those programs into your question.

Comment: After entering sudo apt-get update I got the following:E: Type ‘<!DOCTYPE’ is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.

Comment: After entering sudo apt-get -f install, I got the following response:

Comment: After entering sudo apt-get -f install, I got the following response: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  firefox-locale-af libglademm-2.4-1c2a
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 3 not to upgrade.

Comment: Then I entered apt-get autoremove and got the following:E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?

Comment: Now I do not know what to respond to the question: 'Are you root?'

Comment: Anything else I can try?

Comment: Now I found the Software Updater does not want to respond anymore. I am also not able to install a new printer since yesterday...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove iTunes and fix the Software Center:

1. Uninstall iTunes by deleting the ~/.playonlinux directory, in Terminal (may need to prepend sudo) `rm -rf ~/.playonlinux`
2. Restart your computer
3. Update your sources with `sudo apt-get update`
4. Try opening Software Center

[Source for #1](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/topic-9512-How_to_completely_remove_PlayonLinux_and_Wine.html)

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it did not help my dilemma. Any other suggestions I can try?